# Can the BBP formula be used to prove that Pi is normal?

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

Can the BBP formula be used to prove that Pi is normal?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number

Comment: Welcome to [M.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/). Maybe you should have a look at the ["How To Ask"](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) page!

Comment: Pasted title into question, deleted erroneous tag.

Comment: Changed BPP to BBP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nobody has done it yet, and it hasn't been for lack of trying.  However, Bailey and Crandall have some interesting results showing that there may be some connection there:  see e.g.
http://www.scribd.com/doc/54635409/Random-Generators-and-Normal-Numbers-Bailey-e-Crandall-2003